Puedo ejecutar mi store procedure desde mi smss, mi app pero cuando publico mi aplicación este me manda error
he tratado de publicar una vieja aplicación de .net core 2.1, ya logré que carge la base de datos, pero al ejecutar un store procedure, este me manda error que no tengo los permisos.

Mi cadena de conexión es la siguiente:
"Server=localhos;Database=TUNIWEB;User Id=sa;Password=<contraseña>;"

Ya le di todos los permisos que sql permite, ya lo probe desde modo debug con la misma cadena de conexión y si funciono, también en modo release e igual funciona. Ya probe iniciando sesión como super usuario. Pero igual no funciona.
Y mi store procedure no cumple con algún comando de super usuario.
Este es mi store por si les funciona:
CREATE PROCEDURE Realizarlarelacion(@idalumno uniqueidentifier)
AS
BEGIN
declare @query table(idA uniqueidentifier , idu uniqueidentifier )
declare @query2 table(idA uniqueidentifier , idu uniqueidentifier )
insert into @query  select distinct car.idAlumno, ci.usuarioUniversidad from carrerasDeseadas car join carrerasImpartadas ci on car.idCarrera = ci.catCarrerasId where car.idAlumno = @idalumno
if((select COUNT(re.idAlumno) from @query cu , rechazos re where (cu.ida = re.idAlumno) and (cu.idu = re.idUniversidad) ) > 0)
Begin
/*******/
insert into @query2 select cu.ida, cu.idu from @query cu , rechazos re where (cu.ida != re.idAlumno) and (cu.idu != re.idUniversidad)
/*******/
END
else IF((select COUNT(ac.idalumno) from @query cu , aceptados ac where (cu.ida = ac.idAlumno) and (cu.idu = ac.iduniversidad) )>0)
Begin
/*********/
insert into @query2 select cu.ida, cu.idu from @query cu , aceptados ac where (cu.ida != ac.idAlumno) and (cu.idu != ac.iduniversidad)
/******/
end
else IF((select COUNT(cu.idA)from @query cu, solicitar sol where (cu.idA = sol.idAlumno) and (cu.idu = sol.idUniversidad))>0)
BEGIN
insert into @query2 select cu.idA, cu.idu from @query cu, solicitar sol where (cu.idA != sol.idAlumno) and (cu.idu != sol.idUniversidad)
end
/***Sino se cumple****/
else
begin
/**********/
insert into @query2 select* from @query 
/**********/
end
insert into Relaciones   select*from  @query2
return 1
END

Alguien que haya sufrido lo mismo o que tenga una idea para resolverlo

Ahí dice que el usuario que usas desde tu aplicación no tiene permisos. El usuario sa no necesita asignarle permisos porque es un sysadmin (y es mala práctica el usarlo). Me parece que en algún momento cambia el usuario después de conectarse.
Puedes rastrear el usuario usando Extended Events o Profiler. También podrías simplemente obtener los valores con la siguiente consulta:
SELECT CURRENT_USER, SYSTEM_USER

Eso te dará el usuario de la base de datos y el login que está usando la conexión. Es probable que no sea sa.

Ya vi, resultaba ser que entraba al motor con un usuario y con otro a la base de datos, pero ya lo pude corregir. Gracias
